# Error loading navigation: The Managed Navigation term set is improperly attached to the site

Tags: 2013, 2010

I got this error when I tried to restore site and  content from higher environment to lower environment

Below are the steps I performed

> "top level site settings" -> "Navigation" , selected "Structural
>   navigation" and saved it.

Also

Changed it back to

> "Managed Navigation"

Both didn't help

Comment: I had the exact same issue but after I did what you said above I was then able to go back in and start adding the Termsets, which were then displayed properly.

Comment: worked for me on SP 2013

Answer (score 4):

I just came across this error and I figured out that the cause was one of the terms had not been properly saved. After I clicked the save button, this error no longer appeared. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks man, this helps a lot.

Answer (score 3):

I know this question has been here a long time and probably you have already solved it but today I faced the same problem and I came to this place. What I did was to do exactly same as what you did but at two places: Global Navigation and Current Navigation. It worked perfectly. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

In o365 modern site, ootb managed nav, clicked `create term set`