# Error loading navigation: The Managed Navigation term set is improperly attached to the site. When i restore my Enterprise wiki site collection

Tags: 2013, administration, backup, restore, managed-navigation

I am working on sharepoint server 2013, and i have added an Enterprise wiki site collection and i enable the managed navigation + Friendly URL. now whenever i create a new enterprise wiki page a navigation term will be created automatically. so when i access my Site Setting>> site Navigation. i got the following:-

[image]

where i have navigation terms created under the "Site Navigation".

Now due to some issues where our designer made some bugs layout modifications,  i wanted to restore my enterprise wiki site collection from a backup file which i took today.

so i run the following command to restore from a backup file:-

```
Restore-SPSite http://server_name/sites/site_name -Path C:\Backup\site_name.bak
```

Now the restore completed successfully. but when i access the site collection i got this error :-

```
Error loading navigation: The Managed Navigation term set is improperly attached to the site. (Correlation ID: 7ad0eb9d-fcc8-d003-e007-3d6c1a582fb6)
```

and when i access my Site Settings >> Navigation , i can not find the Site Navigation terms. here is how the site navigation looks like:-

[image]

so please can any one advice , how i can re-connect my site collection with the old terms ?

Comment: what do the ULS logs say for that correlation? Anything juicy? Also, what user account are you using to run Restore-SPSite?

Comment: Agreed, ULS Logs, would be beneficial to help support the question.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the terms did not properly attach to the site, after the restore. Per ([Source #1](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/185594/9345) and [Source #2](http://beginnerssharepointtips.blogspot.com/2014/07/error-loading-navigation-managed.html?_sm_au_=iVV0sjR6VHWVlRJF)), the recommendation appears to be that with the **Site Settings > Navigation**, to select **Structural Navigation** for **Global** and **Current Navigation**, and save it, and set back to **Managed Navigation**. This appears to restore the relationship with the terms, respectively.

Comment: now changing the Navigation settings as you mentioned will remove the error.. but will not reattached the terms with the wiki pages...

Comment: now i find this [link](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/fromthefield/2014/10/13/backuprestore-spsite-and-the-missing-term-set/) which refer to the same problem... but when i try to run the command they mentioned i got the is exception `Exception calling "AddSiteCollectionAccess" with "1" argument(s): "The current
user has insufficient permissions to perform this operation."` .. although i run the command using the farm account which have full permission on all the SP DBs including the managed metadata database.. so not sure what is the problem ?

Comment: If you get an error “Export / Import failed due to insufficient rights”, you will have to open SQL Server Management Studio in the SQL Server machine and make sure that the service account used by managed metadata service application has bulkadmin rights in SQL Server.

Give BulkAdmin rights to the managed metadata service account account as it is required for managed metadata service application import.

Make sure to remove the bulkadmin permissions to the managed metadata service account as soon as you are done with the import/export process.